# shell code assembly segfaults

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a shellcode using the following asm code but I always get a segfault at movl %esi, 0x8(%esi), any idea why? Actually just running the movl %esi, 0x8(%esi) alone makes a seg fault.

```
void main() {
    __asm__(
    "mov $0x80, %edx\n\t"
    "jmp l1\n\t"
    "l2:popl %esi\n\t"
    "movl %esi,0x8(%esi)\n\t"
    "movb $0x0,0x7(%esi)\n\t"
    "movl $0x0,0xc(%esi)\n\t"
    "movl $0xb,%eax\n\t"
    "movl %esi,%ebx\n\t"
    "leal 0x8(%esi),%ecx\n\t"
    "leal 0xc(%esi),%edx\n\t"
    "int $0x80\n\t"
    "movl $0x1, %eax\n\t"
    "movl $0x0, %ebx\n\t"
    "int $0x80\n\t"
    "l1:call l2\n\t"
    ".string \"/bin/sh\"\n\t"
   );
  }
```

Comment: Your code segment (where you placed the string) probably isn't writable. Look into `mprotect(2)`.

Comment: Check what address you're trying to access with 8[ESI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, as user786653 said, that the code segment isn't writable. You can write on the stack, though:

```
subl $0x8, %esp        # make room
movl $0x0, 0x4(%esp)   # null
movl $0x0, (%esp)      # here too
movl $0xb, %eax        # syscall no. 11
movl %esi, %ebx        # pointer to string
leal 0x4(%esp), %ecx   # first null  (argv)
leal (%esp), %edx      # second null (envp)
int $0x80              # go
```